# write a variable to a file on the end of a specific line

Tags: linux, bash, bash-scripting, echo

I want to add a variable to the **end** of a **specific** line in file `file.txt`. My code so far:

```
#!/bin/bash    
read -p "What is the path of the repo? > " input
echo :$input  >> file.txt
```

I want it to add it to **the end** of **line 2**. For example,

```
file.txt
--------
before -
1.stuff 
2./home/retep/awesome

after -
1.stuff
2./home/retep/awesome:/home/retep/cool
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's another one-liner for awk:

```
#!/bin/bash    
read -p "What is the path of the repo? > " input

awk -v addition="$input" -v targetline=2 '
NR==targetline { print $0 ":" addition; next}
{print }' file.txt > file.tmp
mv file.tmp file.txt
```

Comment: it's not working for me. Gives the blank line thingy when you are missing stuff.

Comment: Sorry, I was not concentrated enough. Corrected it.

Comment: doesn't `>` override the file? Can I use `>>`

Comment: If you wish to extend the file that is write something to the END of it, >> is your friend.